# Can I nest a grid inside my bootstrap tab-pane?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using Bootstrap nav-tabs in my page, something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <!--Body content-->


<div class='row>
  <div class='span8'>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
      })
    </script>
  </div>
</div>


        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to organize a grid in my tab-panes, 
I tried this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='span4'>...</div>
    <div class='span4'>...</div>
</div
```

inside panes but that doesn't work.

How do I nest column inside my tab-panes using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/rKaaq/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"></div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">This is some text that spans4</div>
        <div class="span4">This is some more text that spans 4</div>
       </div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
      })
    </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See questions update. The row is inside a row-fluid. I suppose that's the issue

Comment: Nope I just updated it with this: [http://jsfiddle.net/rKaaq/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/rKaaq/1/) and it works fine still

Comment: the beginning of the text in the first span4 is 'hidden' 's is some text that spans4' instead of 'this is some text that spans4' that my issue.

Comment: uh, what? I don't understand what you're trying to say. You want the first span4 to not have text in it but still span4? If that's the case then just remove it and have the one div do this: `<div class="span4 offset4">whatever text you want here</div>`

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/rKaaq/1/ in my span4 I have 'a b c d e f g h' in the result pane you can see that 'a b' was chopped off.

Comment: You have to hit update before it saves, you just pasted the link to the fiddle I had before. But I see what you mean, it looks like .row has a margin-left of -20px; If you override that in your css file of margin-left: 0; it should fix your problem.